# How to find keyword related parts in text?

Tags: javascript, php, search, nlp

I am looking for a way, to find contextually related parts in a document to a given keyword. For example, I want to find parts, that are related to 'happiness'. Which should yield results like:

- ... the boy was very happy ...
- ... a lot of people were celebrating ...
- ... everybody was having a good time ...

I thought about generating related keywords and synonyms and search the text for these, but that might result in a lot of false positives, depending on how many related keywords will be used and the quality of these.

Natural language processing sounded promising, but does not really match this case as far as I can tell. It can tell me the sentiment and extract entities, but I would not know how to solve my problem.

Also it seems really hard to search for, as I do not really know how to formulate the question.

What direction should I be looking in? Is there a science or even a service that I could leverage?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try your suggestion and see exactly how many 'false positives' you actual get... and if it's too many, refine your logic until you are happy

Comment: @musefan if there is no other way of approaching this problem, I will go that route. I am just hoping for a solution that will also match whole phrases and not only keywords.

Comment: Typically the strategy here is to implement a decent machine learning algorithm and then feed it as much training data as you can (i.e. data for which you've manually told the machine what it needs to detect) to help it do classification. Then you can give it real data and hope it can infer the same patterns based on the training. There's always going to be false positives (there's false positives when people communicate with people as well, it's because of the ambiguity of language)

Comment: @apokryfos that sounds reasonable. So I guess I have to let go of the idea of the user choosing a random keyword to look for and find good results, there is no magic bullet. My best bet will be the keyword approach then. Thank you!

Comment: @rootman natural language processing is hard. Even humans (who actually developed it) often have a hard time understanding each other.

Comment: @rootman: Once you have a keyword hit, you can pull the rest of the sentence around it as your full result. Using typically sentence boundary characters (for example, start with any character that isn't a space, letter or number as a boundary)

Comment: @apokryfos Yes you are right ;)

Comment: @musefan that is a good idea!

Comment: Have you given a try to similarity techniques? https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/similarity